# No need for Strong force

Tags: electromagnetism, standard-model, quantum-chromodynamics, quarks, strong-force

As 3 quarks stay inside of proton, where down quark just opposite charge of up quarks then what would happen if I say both of them are attached by their own electromagnetic force instead of strong force?

Answer (score 1):

The strong force isn't posited to explain how quarks stay together in hadrons; quark structures of hadrons are posited to explain the observed strong force between hadrons.

Originally the focus was on the interhadronic force we now call the residual strong force; it's due to the exchange of virtual mesons. Yukawa predicted the then unobserved carrier's mass from the force's range, whose length scale constrains the ability of nucleons to attract each other across a large nucleus (which is why large nuclei need higher neutron-to-proton ratios to be stable in spite of the electrostatic repulsion between protons).

Once it was realised there are many hadrons, the quark model was proposed to explain their observed properties. Hadrons are formed from quarks due to a gluon-carried force felt by both quarks and gluons, the colour force; and the residual strong force is a side-effect of the colour force. (It's the QCD analog of a van der Waals force.) Perhaps the best evidence of the self-interacting colour force's role in the internal structure of hadrons is that, when hadrons are supplied with four-momentum in many-body systems, new hadrons form from the energy instead of the quarks being torn apart.

With supercomputers we can predict hadron masses from quark masses and the potential energy of the colour force using $E=mc^2$. In many cases, including protons and neutrons, most of the mass is due to the latter effect. If you wanted to instead explain a hadron's stability in terms of electromagnetism, which has little effect on a hadron's mass, the simultaneous equations relating quark masses would be much simpler, but the large number of observed hadron masses would not be consistent.

Comment: A telling example:  The ${{\Delta }^{++}}$ consists of *uuu*, which repel electromagnetically but attract via gluon exchange because they have different colors.

Comment: @BertBarrois One hopes a no-strong-force advocate wouldn't instead counter that $\Delta^{++}$ might have composition $uuuudd$ or $uuuuudddd$.

Comment: I think it worth explaining that the “side-effect” that makes nucleons attract is the QCD analog of a van der Waals force between electrically neutral atoms.  It can be modeled by 2-gluon exchange, but it is tricky to reconcile the gluon exchange picture with meson exchange.

Comment: @BertBarrois Good point; I've added that.

Answer (score 0):

The quark model developed slowly from observing the large number of hadronic resonances, classified in the [eightfold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eightfold_Way_(physics)) way,where beautiful symmetries are observed with the so [called flavor su(3)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eightfold_Way_(physics)#Flavor_symmetry) symmetry. It is impossible to reproduce these beautiful plots relying on the u(1) symmetry and photon exchanges between quarks. Take the success of the [Omega baryon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega_baryon)  resonance in the [decuplet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Baryon_decuplet.png), which only has negative quarks .

[image: omega-]

With only electromagnetism it could just not exist, whereas it was a crowning achievement when it was predicted and found experimentally.

> The rationale for the concept of color can be highlighted with the case of the omega-minus, a baryon composed of three strange quarks. Since quarks are fermions with spin 1/2, they must obey the Pauli exclusion principle and cannot exist in identical states. So with three strange quarks, the property which distinguishes them must be capable of at least three distinct values.

There is [other experimental e](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/qevid.html#c1)vidence for the existence of three colors for the strong interaction.

In conclusion , no quark model can exist where the attractive forces are electromagnetic, that can describe the data.